# In SQL Server stored procedure, I need to write a condition, when the parameter value not available in table it should display complete data

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have written a SQL Server stored procedure, which takes 2 parameters. The current stored procedure works as below, when parameter value is available in the column of the table pointing to, it will display the rows specific to that parameter value  only from the table.

Now the requirement is without writing a new stored procedure, I need to write a condition in the same stored procedure so that it should work in such a way that when the user enter any other parameter say 0 value which is not available in table, it should show data of all the SAPID of the table in the output, without filtering.

The parameter I am referring to is the `SAPID` parameter in the below stored procedure, so when user enters any `SAPID` other than `SAPID` available in `msasow` table `GVBDUH` column, it should display all the SAPIDs details without filtering; when we pass in the `SAPID` which is available in the `GVBDUH` column, it will only display data related to that `SAPID` (which is working currently), so when user enter any other `SAPID` which is not available in `GUBDUH` column, it should display data of all SAPIDS available in `GVBDUH` column without filtering

This is my stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetL1AgeingBucket] 
    (@sapid VARCHAR(10),         
     @RagValue VARCHAR(50))          
AS
    DECLARE @temp TABLE
                  (          
                      [Project code] VARCHAR(100),
                      [L3 Sales Name] VARCHAR(100),          
                      PO_NUMBER NVARCHAR(MAX),
                      POValidTo NVARCHAR(MAX),
                      [DU Name] VARCHAR(100),
                      [SDU Name] VARCHAR(100),
                      [VBDU Name] VARCHAR(100),         
                      [Customer Name] VARCHAR(100),
                      [PO KIF] VARCHAR(MAX)          
                  )           

insert into @temp          
select distinct t1.[Project code], t3.[L3 Sales Name], t2.PONumber, CONVERT(varchar(10), t2.[POValidTo], 126),        
t1.[DU Desc (L4)] [DU Name], t1.[SDU Name (L3)] [SDU Name], t1.[VBDU Desc (L2)] [VBDU Name],t1.[Customer Name], t1.[PO KIFID]          
from TBL_MSA_SOW t1           
inner join [tbl_PO] as t2           
on t1.[Project code]=t2.[Project Code]          
inner join [tbl_Sales_mapping] as t3          
on t1.[Project Code]=t3.[Project Code]           
where t2.[PO RAG check]=@RagValue          
and t1.[GVBDUH Code] =@sapid and t3.[AM Sales Name] !='-';          

with cte1 as          
(select distinct t1.[DU Desc (L4)] as [L4], t1.[SDU Name (L3)] as [L3], t1.[VBDU Desc (L2)] as [L2], t3.[Customer Name], t3.[AM Sales Name] as AM,           
 t1.[Project code], t3.[L3 Sales Name] as [Sales L3 Name],           
t3.[L2 sales Name] as [Sales L2 Name], Convert(nvarchar(255),ISNULL(t1.[MSA], ''))+'/'+Convert(nvarchar(255), ISNULL(t1.[MSA KIFNO], '')) as [MSA / KIFNO],     
CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.[MSA End Date], 126) as [MSA End Date], Convert(nvarchar(255),ISNULL(t1.[Customer SOW], ''))+'/'+Convert(nvarchar(255), ISNULL(t1.[SOW KIFNO], '')) as [SOW / KIFNO],    
  CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.[SOW End Date], 126) as [SOW End Date],      
round(t1.[Avg Rev based on AMJ '18 PP (in $K)],0) as [$ K  / Month Impact],  
 t1.[Other KIFID], CONVERT(varchar(10),     
 t1.[Other KIFID End Date], 126) as [Other KIFID End Date],          
t3.[Customer Group]            
from [tbl_MSA_SOW] as t1 left join [tbl_PO] as t2           
on t1.[Project code] = t2.[Project Code]          
inner join [tbl_Sales_mapping] as t3           
on t1.[Project Code]=t3.[Project Code]           
where (t1.[MSA RAG check]=@RagValue or t1.[SOW RAG check]=@RagValue          
or t2.[PO RAG check]=@RagValue)           
and t1.[GVBDUH Code] =@sapid and t3.[AM Sales Name] !='-'          
group by t3.[L3 Sales Name], t3.[AM Sales Name], t1.[DU Desc (L4)] , t1.[SDU Name (L3)], t1.[VBDU Desc (L2)], t3.[Customer Name],           
t1.[Project code], t3.[L2 sales Name],  Convert(nvarchar(255),ISNULL(t1.[MSA], ''))+'/'+Convert(nvarchar(255), ISNULL(t1.[MSA KIFNO], '')),     
CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.[MSA End Date], 126), Convert(nvarchar(255),ISNULL(t1.[Customer SOW], ''))+'/'+Convert(nvarchar(255), ISNULL(t1.[SOW KIFNO], '')),    
CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.[SOW End Date], 126),      
t1.[Avg Rev based on AMJ '18 PP (in $K)], 
t1.[Other KIFID], CONVERT(varchar(10),     
t1.[Other KIFID End Date], 126), t3.[Customer Group]),         

cte2 as          
(select distinct t1.[DU Desc (L4)] as [L4], t1.[SDU Name (L3)] as [L3], t1.[VBDU Desc (L2)] as [L2], t3.[Customer Name], t3.[AM Sales Name] as AM,           
 t1.[Project code], t3.[L3 Sales Name] as [Sales L3 Name],           
t3.[L2 sales Name] as [Sales L2 Name],Convert(nvarchar(255),ISNULL(t1.[MSA], ''))+'/'+Convert(nvarchar(255), ISNULL(t1.[MSA KIFNO], '')) as [MSA / KIFNO],
 CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.[MSA End Date], 126) as [MSA End Date],    
  '' as [SOW / KIFNo], CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.[SOW End Date],    
 126) as [SOW End Date],      
round(t1.[Avg Rev based on AMJ '18 PP (in $K)],0) as [$ K  / Month Impact], t1.[Other KIFID],    
 CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.[Other KIFID End Date], 126) as [Other KIFID End Date]             
from [tbl_MSA_SOW] as t1 left join [tbl_PO] as t2           
on t1.[Project code] = t2.[Project Code]          
inner join [tbl_Sales_mapping] as t3           
on t1.[Project Code]=t3.[Project Code]           
where t1.[MSA RAG check]=@RagValue           
and t1.[GVBDUH Code] =@sapid and t3.[AM Sales Name] !='-'          
group by t3.[L3 Sales Name], t3.[AM Sales Name], t1.[DU Desc (L4)] , t1.[SDU Name (L3)], t1.[VBDU Desc (L2)], t3.[Customer Name],          
t1.[Project code], t3.[L2 sales Name], Convert(nvarchar(255),ISNULL(t1.[MSA], ''))+'/'+Convert(nvarchar(255), ISNULL(t1.[MSA KIFNO], '')),    
CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.[MSA End Date], 126), Convert(nvarchar(255),ISNULL(t1.[Customer SOW], ''))+'/'+Convert(nvarchar(255), ISNULL(t1.[SOW KIFNO], '')), CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.[SOW End Date], 126),       
t1.[Avg Rev based on AMJ '18 PP (in $K)], t1.[Other KIFID], CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.[Other KIFID End Date], 126)),         

cte3 as          
(select distinct t1.[DU Desc (L4)] as [L4], t1.[SDU Name (L3)] as [L3], t1.[VBDU Desc (L2)] as [L2], t3.[Customer Name], t3.[AM Sales Name] as AM,           
 t1.[Project code], t3.[L3 Sales Name] as [Sales L3 Name],           
t3.[L2 sales Name] as [Sales L2 Name],  '' as [MSA / KIFNo], CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.[MSA End Date], 126) as [MSA End Date], Convert(nvarchar(255),ISNULL(t1.[Customer SOW], ''))+'/'+Convert(nvarchar(255), ISNULL(t1.[SOW KIFNO], '')) as [SOW / KIFNO],    
 CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.[SOW End Date], 126) as [SOW End Date],      
round(t1.[Avg Rev based on AMJ '18 PP (in $K)],0) as [$ K  / Month Impact], t1.[Other KIFID],    
 CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.[Other KIFID End Date], 126) as [Other KIFID End Date]            
from [tbl_MSA_SOW] as t1 left join [tbl_PO] as t2           
on t1.[Project code] = t2.[Project Code]          
inner join [tbl_Sales_mapping] as t3           
on t1.[Project Code]=t3.[Project Code]           
where t1.[SOW RAG check]=@RagValue          
and t1.[GVBDUH Code] =@sapid and t3.[AM Sales Name] !='-'          
group by t3.[L3 Sales Name], t3.[AM Sales Name], t1.[DU Desc (L4)], t1.[SDU Name (L3)], t1.[VBDU Desc (L2)], t3.[Customer Name],          
t1.[Project code], t3.[L2 sales Name], Convert(nvarchar(255),ISNULL(t1.[MSA], ''))+'/'+Convert(nvarchar(255), ISNULL(t1.[MSA KIFNO], '')),    
 CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.[MSA End Date], 126), Convert(nvarchar(255),ISNULL(t1.[Customer SOW], ''))+'/'+Convert(nvarchar(255), ISNULL(t1.[SOW KIFNO], '')), CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.[SOW End Date], 126),       
t1.[Avg Rev based on AMJ '18 PP (in $K)], t1.[Other KIFID], CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.[Other KIFID End Date], 126)),      


cte4 as      
(select distinct       
[Project code],[L3 Sales Name],      
[DU Name],[SDU Name],[VBDU Name],[Customer Name],      
 STUFF(      
        (      
        select  ',' + PO_NUMBER FROM @temp d      
        where [Project code]=t.[Project code]              
  for xml path('')      
        ), 1, 1, '') as [PO Numbers],
STUFF(      
        (      
        select  distinct ',' + [PO KIF] FROM @temp d      
        where [Project code]=t.[Project code]              
  for xml path('')      
        ), 1, 1, '') as [PO KIFID]      
 from @temp t),

 cte5 as
(select distinct 
[Project code],[L3 Sales Name],
[DU Name],[SDU Name], [VBDU Name],[Customer Name],
 STUFF(
        (
        select  ',' + POValidTo FROM @temp d
        where [Project code]=t.[Project code]        
        for xml path('')
        ), 1, 1, '') as [PO End Date]   
 from @temp t)   


 SELECT * 
 FROM ( 
 SELECT  A.[Customer Group], A.[Customer Name], A.[L4], A.[L3],UPPER(A.[L2]) L2, A.AM,
A.[Sales L3 Name],           
A.[Sales L2 Name],
A.[MSA / KIFNo],     
A.[MSA End Date], A.[SOW / KIFNo],    
 A.[SOW End Date], A.[PO Numbers],     
 CASE A.[PO Numbers] 
       WHEN NULL THEN '' 
       ELSE  A.[PO KIFID]
END as [PO KIFID] 
 , A.[PO End Date],    
 A.[Other KIFID],     
A.[Other KIFID End Date] , 
sum(A.[$ K  / Month Impact]) AS [$ K  / Month Impact]
  FROM (

select distinct cte1.[Customer Group], cte1.[Customer Name], cte1.[L4], cte1.[L3], cte1.[L2], cte1.AM,           
--cte1.Project, cte1.[Project code],         
cte1.[Sales L3 Name],           
cte1.[Sales L2 Name],        
-- cte2.[MSA No], cte3.[SOW No],         
 cte2.[MSA / KIFNo],     
cte2.[MSA End Date], cte3.[SOW / KIFNo],    
 cte3.[SOW End Date], cte4.[PO Numbers], cte4.[PO KIFID], cte5.[PO End Date],          
cte1.[$ K  / Month Impact], cte1.[Other KIFID],     
cte1.[Other KIFID End Date]        
--cte4.PONumbers         
from cte1           
left join cte2          
on cte1.[Project code]=cte2.[Project code]          
left join cte3          
on cte1.[Project code]=cte3.[Project code]          
left join cte4          
on cte1.[Project code]=cte4.[Project code] 
left join cte5          
on cte1.[Project code]=cte5.[Project code]     
 -- order by cte1.[$ K  / Month Impact] desc           
) A
GROUP BY 
A.[Customer Group], A.[Customer Name], A.[L4], A.[L3], UPPER(A.[L2]), A.AM,
A.[Sales L3 Name],           
A.[Sales L2 Name],
A.[MSA / KIFNo],     
A.[MSA End Date], A.[SOW / KIFNo],    
 A.[SOW End Date], A.[PO Numbers],     
 A.[PO KIFID], A.[PO End Date],      
 A.[Other KIFID],     
A.[Other KIFID End Date] 
         ) B
         ORDER BY B.[$ K  / Month Impact] DESC
```

Comment: This just a change to your `WHERE` clause. You add `OR @SAPID = NULL` after it and when this value is null it just selects everything. This can introduce performance issues however

Comment: We should not compare `@SAPID = NULL`. We should do instead `@SAPID IS NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED

```
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetL1AgeingBucket] 
    (@sapid VARCHAR(10),         
     @RagValue VARCHAR(50))          
AS
    DECLARE @temp TABLE
                  (          
                      [Project code] VARCHAR(100),
                      [L3 Sales Name] VARCHAR(100),          
                      PO_NUMBER NVARCHAR(MAX),
                      POValidTo NVARCHAR(MAX),
                      [DU Name] VARCHAR(100),
                      [SDU Name] VARCHAR(100),
                      [VBDU Name] VARCHAR(100),         
                      [Customer Name] VARCHAR(100),
                      [PO KIF] VARCHAR(MAX)          
                  )           

insert into @temp          
select distinct t1.[Project code], t3.[L3 Sales Name], t2.PONumber, CONVERT(varchar(10), t2.[POValidTo], 126),        
t1.[DU Desc (L4)] [DU Name], t1.[SDU Name (L3)] [SDU Name], t1.[VBDU Desc (L2)] [VBDU Name],t1.[Customer Name], t1.[PO KIFID]          
from TBL_MSA_SOW t1           
inner join [tbl_PO] as t2           
on t1.[Project code]=t2.[Project Code]          
inner join [tbl_Sales_mapping] as t3          
on t1.[Project Code]=t3.[Project Code]           
where t2.[PO RAG check]=@RagValue          
and t1.[GVBDUH Code] = CASE WHEN EXISTS(Select * from TBL_MSA_SOW Where [GVBDUH Code] = @sapid) THEN @sapid ELSE [GVBDUH Code] END and t3.[AM Sales Name] !='-';          

with cte1 as          
(select distinct t1.[DU Desc (L4)] as [L4], t1.[SDU Name (L3)] as [L3], t1.[VBDU Desc (L2)] as [L2], t3.[Customer Name], t3.[AM Sales Name] as AM,           
 t1.[Project code], t3.[L3 Sales Name] as [Sales L3 Name],           
t3.[L2 sales Name] as [Sales L2 Name], Convert(nvarchar(255),ISNULL(t1.[MSA], ''))+'/'+Convert(nvarchar(255), ISNULL(t1.[MSA KIFNO], '')) as [MSA / KIFNO],     
CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.[MSA End Date], 126) as [MSA End Date], Convert(nvarchar(255),ISNULL(t1.[Customer SOW], ''))+'/'+Convert(nvarchar(255), ISNULL(t1.[SOW KIFNO], '')) as [SOW / KIFNO],    
  CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.[SOW End Date], 126) as [SOW End Date],      
round(t1.[Avg Rev based on AMJ '18 PP (in $K)],0) as [$ K  / Month Impact],  
 t1.[Other KIFID], CONVERT(varchar(10),     
 t1.[Other KIFID End Date], 126) as [Other KIFID End Date],          
t3.[Customer Group]            
from [tbl_MSA_SOW] as t1 left join [tbl_PO] as t2           
on t1.[Project code] = t2.[Project Code]          
inner join [tbl_Sales_mapping] as t3           
on t1.[Project Code]=t3.[Project Code]           
where (t1.[MSA RAG check]=@RagValue or t1.[SOW RAG check]=@RagValue          
or t2.[PO RAG check]=@RagValue)           
and t1.[GVBDUH Code] =CASE WHEN EXISTS(Select * from TBL_MSA_SOW Where [GVBDUH Code] = @sapid) THEN @sapid ELSE [GVBDUH Code] END and t3.[AM Sales Name] !='-'          
group by t3.[L3 Sales Name], t3.[AM Sales Name], t1.[DU Desc (L4)] , t1.[SDU Name (L3)], t1.[VBDU Desc (L2)], t3.[Customer Name],           
t1.[Project code], t3.[L2 sales Name],  Convert(nvarchar(255),ISNULL(t1.[MSA], ''))+'/'+Convert(nvarchar(255), ISNULL(t1.[MSA KIFNO], '')),     
CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.[MSA End Date], 126), Convert(nvarchar(255),ISNULL(t1.[Customer SOW], ''))+'/'+Convert(nvarchar(255), ISNULL(t1.[SOW KIFNO], '')),    
CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.[SOW End Date], 126),      
t1.[Avg Rev based on AMJ '18 PP (in $K)], 
t1.[Other KIFID], CONVERT(varchar(10),     
t1.[Other KIFID End Date], 126), t3.[Customer Group]),         

cte2 as          
(select distinct t1.[DU Desc (L4)] as [L4], t1.[SDU Name (L3)] as [L3], t1.[VBDU Desc (L2)] as [L2], t3.[Customer Name], t3.[AM Sales Name] as AM,           
 t1.[Project code], t3.[L3 Sales Name] as [Sales L3 Name],           
t3.[L2 sales Name] as [Sales L2 Name],Convert(nvarchar(255),ISNULL(t1.[MSA], ''))+'/'+Convert(nvarchar(255), ISNULL(t1.[MSA KIFNO], '')) as [MSA / KIFNO],
 CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.[MSA End Date], 126) as [MSA End Date],    
  '' as [SOW / KIFNo], CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.[SOW End Date],    
 126) as [SOW End Date],      
round(t1.[Avg Rev based on AMJ '18 PP (in $K)],0) as [$ K  / Month Impact], t1.[Other KIFID],    
 CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.[Other KIFID End Date], 126) as [Other KIFID End Date]             
from [tbl_MSA_SOW] as t1 left join [tbl_PO] as t2           
on t1.[Project code] = t2.[Project Code]          
inner join [tbl_Sales_mapping] as t3           
on t1.[Project Code]=t3.[Project Code]           
where t1.[MSA RAG check]=@RagValue           
and t1.[GVBDUH Code] =CASE WHEN EXISTS(Select * from TBL_MSA_SOW Where [GVBDUH Code] = @sapid) THEN @sapid ELSE [GVBDUH Code] END and t3.[AM Sales Name] !='-'          
group by t3.[L3 Sales Name], t3.[AM Sales Name], t1.[DU Desc (L4)] , t1.[SDU Name (L3)], t1.[VBDU Desc (L2)], t3.[Customer Name],          
t1.[Project code], t3.[L2 sales Name], Convert(nvarchar(255),ISNULL(t1.[MSA], ''))+'/'+Convert(nvarchar(255), ISNULL(t1.[MSA KIFNO], '')),    
CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.[MSA End Date], 126), Convert(nvarchar(255),ISNULL(t1.[Customer SOW], ''))+'/'+Convert(nvarchar(255), ISNULL(t1.[SOW KIFNO], '')), CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.[SOW End Date], 126),       
t1.[Avg Rev based on AMJ '18 PP (in $K)], t1.[Other KIFID], CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.[Other KIFID End Date], 126)),         

cte3 as          
(select distinct t1.[DU Desc (L4)] as [L4], t1.[SDU Name (L3)] as [L3], t1.[VBDU Desc (L2)] as [L2], t3.[Customer Name], t3.[AM Sales Name] as AM,           
 t1.[Project code], t3.[L3 Sales Name] as [Sales L3 Name],           
t3.[L2 sales Name] as [Sales L2 Name],  '' as [MSA / KIFNo], CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.[MSA End Date], 126) as [MSA End Date], Convert(nvarchar(255),ISNULL(t1.[Customer SOW], ''))+'/'+Convert(nvarchar(255), ISNULL(t1.[SOW KIFNO], '')) as [SOW / KIFNO],    
 CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.[SOW End Date], 126) as [SOW End Date],      
round(t1.[Avg Rev based on AMJ '18 PP (in $K)],0) as [$ K  / Month Impact], t1.[Other KIFID],    
 CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.[Other KIFID End Date], 126) as [Other KIFID End Date]            
from [tbl_MSA_SOW] as t1 left join [tbl_PO] as t2           
on t1.[Project code] = t2.[Project Code]          
inner join [tbl_Sales_mapping] as t3           
on t1.[Project Code]=t3.[Project Code]           
where t1.[SOW RAG check]=@RagValue          
and t1.[GVBDUH Code] =CASE WHEN EXISTS(Select * from TBL_MSA_SOW Where [GVBDUH Code] = @sapid) THEN @sapid ELSE [GVBDUH Code] END and t3.[AM Sales Name] !='-'          
group by t3.[L3 Sales Name], t3.[AM Sales Name], t1.[DU Desc (L4)], t1.[SDU Name (L3)], t1.[VBDU Desc (L2)], t3.[Customer Name],          
t1.[Project code], t3.[L2 sales Name], Convert(nvarchar(255),ISNULL(t1.[MSA], ''))+'/'+Convert(nvarchar(255), ISNULL(t1.[MSA KIFNO], '')),    
 CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.[MSA End Date], 126), Convert(nvarchar(255),ISNULL(t1.[Customer SOW], ''))+'/'+Convert(nvarchar(255), ISNULL(t1.[SOW KIFNO], '')), CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.[SOW End Date], 126),       
t1.[Avg Rev based on AMJ '18 PP (in $K)], t1.[Other KIFID], CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.[Other KIFID End Date], 126)),      


cte4 as      
(select distinct       
[Project code],[L3 Sales Name],      
[DU Name],[SDU Name],[VBDU Name],[Customer Name],      
 STUFF(      
        (      
        select  ',' + PO_NUMBER FROM @temp d      
        where [Project code]=t.[Project code]              
  for xml path('')      
        ), 1, 1, '') as [PO Numbers],
STUFF(      
        (      
        select  distinct ',' + [PO KIF] FROM @temp d      
        where [Project code]=t.[Project code]              
  for xml path('')      
        ), 1, 1, '') as [PO KIFID]      
 from @temp t),

 cte5 as
(select distinct 
[Project code],[L3 Sales Name],
[DU Name],[SDU Name], [VBDU Name],[Customer Name],
 STUFF(
        (
        select  ',' + POValidTo FROM @temp d
        where [Project code]=t.[Project code]        
        for xml path('')
        ), 1, 1, '') as [PO End Date]   
 from @temp t)   


 SELECT * 
 FROM ( 
 SELECT  A.[Customer Group], A.[Customer Name], A.[L4], A.[L3],UPPER(A.[L2]) L2, A.AM,
A.[Sales L3 Name],           
A.[Sales L2 Name],
A.[MSA / KIFNo],     
A.[MSA End Date], A.[SOW / KIFNo],    
 A.[SOW End Date], A.[PO Numbers],     
 CASE A.[PO Numbers] 
       WHEN NULL THEN '' 
       ELSE  A.[PO KIFID]
END as [PO KIFID] 
 , A.[PO End Date],    
 A.[Other KIFID],     
A.[Other KIFID End Date] , 
sum(A.[$ K  / Month Impact]) AS [$ K  / Month Impact]
  FROM (

select distinct cte1.[Customer Group], cte1.[Customer Name], cte1.[L4], cte1.[L3], cte1.[L2], cte1.AM,           
--cte1.Project, cte1.[Project code],         
cte1.[Sales L3 Name],           
cte1.[Sales L2 Name],        
-- cte2.[MSA No], cte3.[SOW No],         
 cte2.[MSA / KIFNo],     
cte2.[MSA End Date], cte3.[SOW / KIFNo],    
 cte3.[SOW End Date], cte4.[PO Numbers], cte4.[PO KIFID], cte5.[PO End Date],          
cte1.[$ K  / Month Impact], cte1.[Other KIFID],     
cte1.[Other KIFID End Date]        
--cte4.PONumbers         
from cte1           
left join cte2          
on cte1.[Project code]=cte2.[Project code]          
left join cte3          
on cte1.[Project code]=cte3.[Project code]          
left join cte4          
on cte1.[Project code]=cte4.[Project code] 
left join cte5          
on cte1.[Project code]=cte5.[Project code]     
 -- order by cte1.[$ K  / Month Impact] desc           
) A
GROUP BY 
A.[Customer Group], A.[Customer Name], A.[L4], A.[L3], UPPER(A.[L2]), A.AM,
A.[Sales L3 Name],           
A.[Sales L2 Name],
A.[MSA / KIFNo],     
A.[MSA End Date], A.[SOW / KIFNo],    
 A.[SOW End Date], A.[PO Numbers],     
 A.[PO KIFID], A.[PO End Date],      
 A.[Other KIFID],     
A.[Other KIFID End Date] 
         ) B
         ORDER BY B.[$ K  / Month Impact] DESC
```

Comment: Hi Syed, can you help me where exactly i need to place the above lines in my stored procedure, to make it work

Comment: @santoshkumar check my edited answer, i have updated your where clause with case and exists.

Comment: Hi Syed Wahhab, thanks a lot for your help, its working as per requirement